# AngularJs, change menu item whether user is connected or not

Tags: angularjs, authentication, angularjs-directive, navbar

I am new to AngularJS and I try to deal with user authentication.

I ensure non connected user can't access restricted route :

**app.js**

```
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/myroute', {
          templateUrl: 'views/myroute.html',
          controller: 'MyrouteCtrl',
            access: {
                isFreeAccess: false
            }
        })
 ...
 .run( function ($rootScope, $location, Auth) {

    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(currRoute, prevRoute){

        if (prevRoute.access != undefined) {
            // if route requires auth and user is not logged in
            if (!prevRoute.access.isFreeAccess && !Auth.isLogged) {
                // redirects to index
                $location.path('/');
            }
        }
```

**AuthService.js**

```
.factory('Auth', function () {
    var user;

    return{
        setUser : function(aUser){
            user = aUser;
        },
        isLoggedIn : function(){
            return(user)? user : false;
        }
    }
});
```

**login.js**

```
$scope.login = function(user) {

    $http({
        url: ***,
        method: "POST",
        data: user,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.persons = data;

            Auth.setUser(data); //Update the state of the user in the app

            $location.path("/");
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.status = status;
    });
```

User state is stored when he's connected. Now I would like to display new items in the navbar.

**index.html**

```
<div ng-include src="'views/navbar.html'"></div>
```

**navbar.js**

```
.controller('NavbarCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.items = [
        {'name': 'Home', "needAuthentication": false},
        {'name': 'About', "needAuthentication": false},
        {'name': 'Settings', "needAuthentication": true},
        {'name': 'Logout', "needAuthentication": true}
    ];
});
```

**navbar.html**

```
<div ng-controller="NavbarCtrl" class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse" role="navigation">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li ng-repeat="item in items ">
               <a ng-if="item.needAuthentication == false || (item.needAuthentication == true && Auth.isLoggedIn())" href="#{{item.name}}">{{item.name}}</a> 
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

When user launches the app :

1) He is not connected yet

```
ng-if="item.needAuthentication == false || (item.needAuthentication == true && Auth.isLoggedIn ())"
```

'Home' and 'About' items are displayed.

2) Then he connects to the app, but the navbar is not rerendered with other items ('Settings' and 'logout').

What is the proper way to achieve that ? To use a directive / bind it to a model / or something else ?

thx in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think the `isLoogged` function should return true when `user` is defined

try changing

```
return(user)? user : false;
```

to

```
return(user)? true : false;
```

Comment: I have already tried this solution but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Ok, in your controller, Auth is not instantiated, if factories work the same way as services then they should be included in the controller definition as, `.controller('NavbarCtrl', function ($scope, Auth)` and also try using `Auth.isLogged()`

Comment: I moved the condition of navBar view in a simple function in the navBar controller.  `$scope.condition = function(item) {
            return item.needAuthentication == false || (item.needAuthentication == true && Auth.isLoggedIn());
        };`. It made the job, I don't know why it doesn't work when I put the condition 'Auth.isLoggedIn()' directly in the ng-if directive of my view (even when I instantiate Auth in the controller. Thx for you help !