# AngularJS show login/logout in menu based on user status

Tags: angularjs, menu, controller, partial-views

I am making a simple angularJS application and pretty new to it. I have a menu like this

home login

I want the login to change to logout if the user has successfully loggin in. I have implemented the login (psuedo implenation), the probem I am facing is, my menu is at the top out out '

I looked at this question [AngularJs, change menu item whether user is connected or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23322733/angularjs-change-menu-item-whether-user-is-connected-or-not) but I could not get my problem solved with it.

How do I fix this? My controller for home looks like this

```
scotchApp.controller('mainController', function($scope, user) {

// create a message to display in our view
$scope.isUserLoggedIn = user.getSession();
$scope.message = 'Everyone come and see how good I look!' + user.getSession();
$scope.submit = function(){ 
     alert('Thank you. Request is sent successfully');
     $('#SupportModal').modal('hide');
};
});
```

where user is FactoryService. That part is working fine. Any help is appreciated.

If I show {{isUserLoggedIn}} value next to menu it always show false, which is the problem. But if I put that in home.html, it show correct value. The problem is I can't build the logic with {{isUserLoggedIn}} in the menu.

Comment: On which HTML tag is your "ng-controller" ? The $scope of your controller can only be used within this tag.

Comment: yes, that is the problem. `<body ng-app="scotchApp"  ng-controller="mainController">`. the problem though partial views are rendered within <ng-view></ng-view> tag. My menu is in the top, outside ng-view. I think I have to use directive?

Comment: Nope, you're actually facing the main trouble about the built-in angular router. I recomend you to take a look at https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router . You could also simply add a controller for your top part directly via ng-controller. But ui-router is a better way to go.

Comment: @Okazari thanks for guiding me in the right direction. Let me look into this. Is this ui-router different than main router?

Comment: Yes it is. You can add nested view. (that's the main thing) and refer to states instead of URL. I'll give your a plunker exemple in a few moment

Comment: Here is the exemple http://plnkr.co/edit/T5vEJf1JNWR8xoKitlRJ?p=preview, hope it helped

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you to use [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router).
It provide nested views and will help you a lot with this issue.

Here is a quick example(in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/T5vEJf1JNWR8xoKitlRJ?p=preview)) of how to use it in your case (really simplified) :

Here is how your states should look :

```
$stateProvider
  .state('app', {
    templateUrl: 'head.html',
    controller: 'HeadCtrl',
  })
  .state('app.feature1', {
    url:'/feature1',
    templateUrl: 'feature1.html',
    controller:'FeatureCtrl'
  })
```

And your differents HTML files :

Index.html (just showing the body part) :

```
<body ng-app="testApp">
    <ui-view></ui-view>
</body>
```

Head.html :

```
<div>
  <div class="header">
    You are currently <span ng-show="user.connected">connected</span><span ng-show="!user.connected">disconnected</span>
  </div>
  <ui-view></ui-view>
</div>
```

feature1.html

```
<div class="page">
  <div>
    I am Bill <button ng-click="connect()">Connect as Bill</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    I am Steve <button ng-click="connect(1)">Connect as Steve</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button ng-click="disconnect()">Disconnect</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

What you need to understand is that if you reach the "/feature1" url, you will be in state `app` and its substate `feature1` (state `app.feature1`)

The first `ui-view` will be filed by `app` state's template. The `ui-view` in the template will be filed by `feature1` state's template.

I know this is a bit unclear, but try to follow a "gettting started" guide and this exemple should help you a lot.

Hope it helped